# How to export WATCH panel variable while debugging in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to export my variable "dataSets" in the WATCH panel as a list or JSON. Is this possible?

Working: TypeScript/JavaScript

[image]

Comment: in the debug console you can print/JSONify the variable and then copy-paste that text

Comment: @rioV8 that is really nice idea! Thanks.

 do you know if it actually is copying the entire variable with all its indentation? (wasn't able to try it out yet)

Comment: if you have a JSON version of the variable you can write a nice JS script to beautify it, or somebody already has done this